# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLCollection> has no method 'tags'

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried to fix this but i must be missing something simple. This is a javascript menu and it works fine in IE but in chrome, the first level click to open the menu fails with the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLCollection> has no method 'tags'
```

Something tells me one of the elements isn't correctly defined but I dont see it.

Here is a simple working example

http://code.fraser.id.au/menu.html

NOTE: Pull down (Windows Sytle) menu top left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the right way to get child nodes by tag name is `getElementsByTagName`: http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM:element.getElementsByTagName

Comment: Awesome, this worked perfectly. Its an old routine so needed some updating.
`var tList = el.getElementsByTagName("table");`